# encryption key is too short, see security.yml.example

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, canvas-lms

OS - Ubuntu 16
Date - 11/06/2017

I'm trying to install `Canvas LMS` on my local computer.

Following `"https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Production-Start"` this link

Step One - Database installation and configuration

1. Installing Postgres

   ```
   a. sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3
   ```

   but i'm getting an error

   > ('postgresql-9.3' has no installation candidate)

   So, I used bellow commands

   ```
   a. sudo apt-get update
   b. sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
   ```
2. Configuring `Postgres`

   ```
   a. sudo -u postgres createuser canvas --no-createdb \
     --no-superuser --no-createrole --pwprompt (i set password `'portal'`)

   b. sudo -u postgres createdb canvas_production --owner=canvas
   ```

Step Two - Getting the code

1. Using Git

   ```
   a. sudo apt-get install git-core
   b. git clone https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms.git canvas
   c. cd canvas
   d. git branch --set-upstream-to origin/stable
   ```
2. Code installation

   ```
   a. sudo mkdir -p /var/canvas
   b. sudo chown -R anup /var/canvas
   c. cd canvas
   d. sudo cp -av . /var/canvas
   e. cd /var/canvas
   ```

Step Three - Dependency Installation

1. External dependencies

   ```
   a. sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
   b. sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
   c. sudo apt-get update

   d. sudo apt-get install ruby2.4 ruby2.4-dev zlib1g-dev libxml2-dev \
                  libsqlite3-dev postgresql libpq-dev \
                  libxmlsec1-dev curl make g++

   e. curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
   f. sudo apt-get install nodejs

   g. sudo -u postgres createuser ultron
   h. sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter user ultron with superuser" postgres
   ```

Step Four - Ruby Gems

1. Bundler and Canvas dependencies

   ```
   a. sudo gem install bundler --version 1.13.6
   b. bundle install --path vendor/bundle
   ```
2. `Yarn` Installation

   ```
   a. curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   b. echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

   c. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --allow-downgrades yarn=0.27.5-1 (Cause i'm using Ubuntu 16)

   d. sudo apt-get install python

   e. yarn install
   ```

Step Five - Canvas default configuration

1. ```
     a. for config in amazon_s3 database \
      delayed_jobs domain file_store outgoing_mail security external_migration; \
    do cp config/$config.yml.example config/$config.yml; done
   ```
2. Dynamic settings configuration

   ```
     a. cp config/dynamic_settings.yml.example config/dynamic_settings.yml
     b. nano config/dynamic_settings.yml (Haven't Changed anything)
   ```
3. Database configuration

   ```
     a. cp config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
     b. nano config/database.yml
   ```

have changed From -

```
--# do not create a queue: section for your test environment
--test:
--  adapter: postgresql
--  encoding: utf8
--  database: canvas_test
--  host: localhost
--  username: canvas
--  timeout: 5000
--
--development:
--  adapter: postgresql
--  encoding: utf8
--  database: canvas_development
--  timeout: 5000

--production:
--  adapter: postgresql
--  encoding: utf8
--  database: canvas_production
--  host: localhost
--  username: canvas
--  password: portal
--  timeout: 5000
```

to this

```
--# do not create a queue: section for your test environment
--test:
--  adapter: postgresql
--  encoding: utf8
--  database: canvas_test
--  host: localhost
--  username: canvas
--  timeout: 5000

--development:
--  adapter: postgresql
--  encoding: utf8
--  database: canvas_production
--  host: localhost
--  username: canvas
--  password: portal
--  timeout: 5000

--production:
--  adapter: postgresql
--  encoding: utf8
--  database: canvas_production
--  host: localhost
--  username: canvas
--  password: portal
--  timeout: 5000
```

4. Outgoing mail configuration

   ```
   a. cp config/outgoing_mail.yml.example config/outgoing_mail.yml
   b. nano config/outgoing_mail.yml (Haven't Changed anything)
   ```
5. URL configuration

   ```
   a. cp config/domain.yml.example config/domain.yml
   b. nano config/domain.yml
   ```
6. Security configuration
   a. cp config/security.yml.example config/security.yml
   b. nano config/security.yml

Step Six - Generate Assets

```
  1. 
    a. cd /var/canvas
    b. mkdir -p log tmp/pids public/assets app/stylesheets/brandable_css_brands
    c. touch app/stylesheets/_brandable_variables_defaults_autogenerated.scss
    d. touch Gemfile.lock
    e. sudo chown -R anup config/environment.rb log tmp public/assets \

    app/stylesheets/_brandable_variables_defaults_autogenerated.scss \
                          app/stylesheets/brandable_css_brands Gemfile.lock config.ru

    f. yarn install
    g. RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake canvas:compile_assets
```

> Error - encryption key is too short, see security.yml.example, so i
>   changed the sequrity.yml.example

From this -

```
--production:
--  # replace this with a random string of at least 20 characters
--  encryption_key: 12345

--development:
--  encryption_key: facdd3a131ddd8988b14f6e4e01039c93cfa0160
--  previous_encryption_keys:
--    - 0610afc39c93010e4e6f41b8898ddd131a3ddcaf

--test:
--  encryption_key: facdd3a131ddd8988b14f6e4e01039c93cfa0160
```

to this -

```
--production:
--  # replace this with a random string of at least 20 characters
--  encryption_key: facdd3a131ddd8988b14f6e4e01039c93cfa0160
--development:
--  encryption_key: facdd3a131ddd8988b14f6e4e01039c93cfa0160
--  previous_encryption_keys:
--    - 0610afc39c93010e4e6f41b8898ddd131a3ddcaf

--test:
--  encryption_key: facdd3a131ddd8988b14f6e4e01039c93cfa0160
```

Problem Not resolved - Whatever i'm putting there getting the same error

```
    h. sudo chown -R anup public/dist/brandable_css
Getting this error -
```

> cannot access 'public/dist/brandable_css': No such file or directory

I'm stuck here, Please Help

Thank you!

Comment: Does the file public/dist/brandable_css actually exist? What is in it? Can you do `ls -als public/dist/brandable_css` to show the permissions too. BTW You should consider putting the log snippets and code into code blocks when you edit to make it more readable

Comment: I don't understand. Your final error after fixing the security keys appears to be **cannot access 'public/dist/brandable_css': No such file or directory**. Is that not really the error? If you still have problems with the security.yml file, can you check that it is formatted correctly and named correctly (no typos).

Comment: Thank you!  @Phil , thank for the suggestion, Hope now you can see the problem, first problem i'v got is "encryption key is too short, see security.yml.example" which is not resolved, so i tried to run "sudo chown -R anup public/dist/brandable_css"

Comment: I'm assuming that your yaml does not have the `--` marks in the text? Or do those appear?

Comment: @Phil, Yes you are right, it does not have -- marks.

Comment: Can you show the a few full lines of the log file where the error is occurring. It might be useful to see the context, and the module name/line that it is failing in.

Comment: Which log file ? Can you tell me the path of that file?

Comment: `log/production.log` as you are failing when using `RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: You say you changed `security.yml.example`. You actually need to change `security.yml`. Could you post the exact content of `security.yml`

Comment: This is the exact content of security.yml - production:
  # replace this with a random string of at least 20 characters
  encryption_key: 12345

development:
  encryption_key: facdd3a131ddd8988b14f6e4e01039c93cfa0160
  previous_encryption_keys:
    - 0610afc39c93010e4e6f41b8898ddd131a3ddcaf

test:
  encryption_key: facdd3a131ddd8988b14f6e4e01039c93cfa0160

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I have changed the security.yml and it started working.

Comment: Good to hear. Please mark my simple answer based on this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick answer to the question, based on the lengthy series of comments.

The file security.yml needed to be edited, rather than security.yml.example.